# How do I display a worksheet by name using VSTO 2010 for Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have never used VSTO and I am finding it difficult to find a good learning aid for 2010.

My need is simple, I have a business workbook with 42 worksheets (I orignally guessed 20 but after counting found a surprising number). I want to add a ribbon (That part is easy) using VSTO to allow employees to navigate the large number of pages easily. I cannot seem to find the c# code to display a specific worksheet (Preferably by name) that I can simply add to the click event of the buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call the `Activate` method on the worksheet object (of type `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet`).

You can do this by name from within your `ThisWorkbook` class or via `Globals.ThisWorkbook` as follows:

```
private Excel.Worksheet GetWorksheetByName(string name)
{
  foreach (Excel.Worksheet worksheet in this.Worksheets)
  {
    if (worksheet.Name == name)
    {
      return worksheet;
    }
  }
  throw new ArgumentException();
}

private void ActivateWorksheetByName(string name)
{
  GetWorksheetByName(name).Activate();
}
```

Call the `ActivateWorksheetByName` and pass the name of the worksheet to show.

Comment: How do I access the ThisWorkBook instance from within the Ribbon Class? I can't seem to get a hook on it and I obviously don't want to new up another one.

Comment: You can access it via the `Globals` class as `Globals.ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I will try that as soon as I get into the office. I deperately need to find a good VSTO 2010 book. It seems that 99% of what I find on the web is outdated and I don't know enough to tell which 1% would be useful.

Comment: The books by Eric Carter/Eric Lippert are good but I don't think there's a new edition for VSTO 2010 (version 4.0). However, most of the material for VSTO 2007 (version 3.0) is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Oddly I get a compiler warning that the .Activate() is ambiguous between the method and event (It is using the method so it works fine) but it will not accept the full namespace. I appreciate your time, this solves my immediate issue and gives me a minor introduction into VSTO. Believe me I will buy the book when it is avaialbe.. I am not going to wait for the movie.

Comment: All VSTO 3.0 stuff I have read is fine. VSTO 4(VS 2010) has very little changes to the model, just new features that make things easy to debug and deploy. VSTO 2.0 (VS 2005) has quite a number of breaking changes. Stick to the VSTO 3.0/4.0 articles and you'll be fine.

Comment: I know its late, however, to remove the ambiguous warning you need to cast to a _Worksheet.  I.E. ((Excel._Worksheet)sheet).Activate();